# PostgreSQL: FATAL: XX000: could not write init file

Tags: postgresql

I got this error when I tried to access DB from the live instance Server.
Anyone knows the reason ?

Comment: Have you checked the log? check the disk space and free up some space it worked for me.

Comment: I have checked the log file, you are correct. It consumed all space. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

It could be becuse of there is no free space on your hard drives

Comment: Just try to delete some file to clean up your computer to get the space, and then everything is working good.